# Displaying Search Results in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableViewController` and I've added a search bar as the header view. I'm trying to get the table view data to reload when the text in the search bar changes but it's not working.

Here is my `textDidChange` method. For context, `jsonArray` is `[[String: AnyObject]]` and is passed from another view controller. The searchResults array is then set to `jsonArray` in `viewDidLoad()` and the table view uses searchResults as it's data source.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
            searchResults?.removeAll()
            searchResults = jsonArray!
        } else {
            searchResults?.removeAll()
            for market in jsonArray! {
                let titleRange = market["name"]?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)

                var address = String()
                var city = String()
                var state = String()
                var zip = Int()

                if let address1 = market["address1"] as? String {
                    address = address1
                }

                if let city1 = market["city"] as? String {
                    city = city1
                }

                if let state1 = market["state"] as? String {
                    state = state1
                }

                if let zip1 = market["zip"] as? Int {
                    zip = zip1
                }

                let zipCode = String(describing: zip)
                let addressString = String("\(address) " + "\(city), " + "\(state) " + "\(zipCode)")
                let addressRange = addressString?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)

                if titleRange != nil {
                    searchResults?.append(market)
                } else if addressRange != nil {
                    searchResults?.append(market)
                }
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I've added this print statement at the end of the else statement after the for loop and it's showing that the array contains all of the objects it contained originally so it looks like my ranges aren't working correctly.

```
print("search array: \(searchResults?.count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using NSRange instead of Range in Swift.

```
let titleNSRange: NSRange = (market["name"]?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive))!
let addressNSRange: NSRange = (addressNSString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive))

if titleNSRange.location != NSNotFound || addressNSRange.location != NSNotFound {
                    searchResults?.append(market)
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

you Don't need to call searchResults?.removeAll() function instead you use it

```
    searchResults = NSMutableArray.init()
```

Don't use searchResults?.append(market) instead use it

```
    searchResults.addObject(market)
```

Comment: I'm using Swift arrays, not NSArray.